# git: updating an old repo with all of the changes in a new repo

Tags: git

Wondering what the best way to go about updating repo B with the changes in repo A.

I have repo A in a Stash repo, which was last updated 1 year 9 months ago.

I have repo B in a BitBucket repo, which was last updated several months ago. In the git logs I can see that the last commit to repo A is contained within the logs of repo B.

So far, what I've tried is cloning repo B, changing the git remote origin to that of repo A, `git pull origin master`, and then push the changes. However, I get a `remote rejected: pre-receive hook declined`.

I definitely want to transfer all of the commit logs from repo B into repo A.